HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Sensor not reading
I have two HC-SR04 from Sparkfun  and looking to follow this tutorial(link below) while using 2x sensors. 1 is reading continuously and operating fine while the other appears to be reading zero, regardless of what i/o ports they are plugged into the Arduino Uno R3 in port 6 and 7 , using the exact code on this tutorial. I do appear to have power to both, indicated by the red LED.
I am using The mechatronics tutorial to troubleshoot the main objective in the instructables.com tutorial.
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/#how-the-hc-sr04-ultrasonic-distance-sensor-works .
https://www.instructables.com/Dual-Sensor-Echo-Locator/
My hardware configuration does not include the LCD mentioned in the mechatronics tutorial. When the nonfunction sensor is plugged in, it reads zero every second. The full hardware configuration is using 2x ultrasonic sensors. Secondary schematic is for reference from the mechatronics tutorial.
Update 12/11- I have realized both Trig and Echo pins must PWM IO ports on my Arduino. I believe I have a hardware problem where the jumper wires are not properly connected to the second sensor. You can find my actual code trying to troubleshoot my second sensor in an effort to simplify my troubleshooting.
/*
Micro controller - Arduino Uno R3
IDE VERSION: 2.2.3
Last opened: 24-01207
Version-
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/
arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/#how-the-hc-sr04-ultrasonic-distance-sensor-works
1x sensor works 6/7
*/

const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin
const int aleft = 7;
const int bright = 8;
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 10;
const int echoPin = 11;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
  Serial.println("debug_basic started.");
}
void loop() {
  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}


I'd like to be able to use both ultrasonic sensors. Any suggestions on what my next troubleshooting steps should be? Thanks in advance! -MP



your next steps should be to add the schematic diagram of the circuit to your question, and to add the code to your question

The schematic is in the how-to mechatronics link provided.

please do not post links ... your question becomes useless when the link dies

Have you looked up the updated Post?

you did not read all of my comment ... your wiring diagram has only one sensor ... maybe the second sensor returns zero values because it does not exist

@MichaelP The code you used is also requested and still missing.

I am using the code from the mechatronics tutorial. Post is fully updated now

@MichaelP Isn't that for a single sensor? So you must have modified it. Insert your code into your question instead of giving links to code you are not anyway using.

Post is fully updated now .. no it is not ... your code is still missing

@MichaelP your question and answers to your question are not just for you ... they are a research repository for people that have a similar electronics design question in the future ... your insistence in using links jeopardizes the usefulness of the question and of any subsequent answers ... please make the question self-contained by removing the links and adding all necessary information into the question directly

Have you replaced or swapped the two US boards to see if they both works? Did you complete the whole "Arduino" and "Processing" tutorial programs?

@Antonio51 I am just trying to get consistent readings in the Arduino serial line for now.

@jsotola  I have realized both Trig and Echo pins must PWM IO ports on my Arduino. I believe I have a hardware problem where the jumper wires are not properly connected to the second sensor. You can find my actual code trying to troubleshoot my second sensor in an effort to simplify my troubleshooting.
